# How to wait for event to happen without blocking?

Tags: java, concurrency, akka

I'd like my actor to wait for some event to occur, but I want it to still receive messages and proceed with messages. How can I achieve it?

My code is as follows:

```
class MyActor extends UntypedActor {
     //onReceive implementation etc...

     private void doSomething(ActorRef other){
         String decision = (String) Await.result(ask(other, new String("getDecision"),1000), Duration.create(1, SECONDS));
         while(decision.equals(""){
              Thread.sleep(100)
              decision = (String) Await.result(ask(other, new String("getDecision"),1000), Duration.create(1, SECONDS));
         }
     }
}
```

But this blocks entire actor until it receives proper decision. How can I achieve something like that without blocking my actor ?

Comment: Rather than waiting on the future, pipe its result back to `self` and then figure out the next step (try again, move on, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of code is the good candidate for the use of `Futures`.

You can find more information here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html

In your case, it would look like:

```
final ExecutionContext ec = context().dispatcher();

private void doSomething(ActorRef other){
    Future<Object> decision = (Patterns.ask(other, new String("getDecision"), 1000));
    decision.onSuccess(new OnSuccess<Object>() {
        public void onSuccess(Object result) {
            String resultString = (String) result;
            System.out.println("Decision: " + result);
        }
    }, ec);
}
```

You should always try to avoid `Await.result` which like you said causes the thread to block. You can use callbacks such as `onSuccess` or `onComplete` to execute code once the future returns without waiting for the result.

Comment: "Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'akka.dispatch.OnSuccess<java.lang.String>', required: 'scala.PartialFunction<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>' 

onSuccess
(scala.PartialFunction<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>,
ExecutionContext)
in Future cannot be applied
to (anonymous akka.dispatch.OnSuccess<java.lang.String>, ExecutionContext)"

Comment: I've edited my answer to get rid of this type error, now I work with `Object`s and I make the cast to `String` in the `onSuccess` method.

Comment: BTW, if you're going to work with Akka, I suggest you take a look at Scala, the Akka syntax in Scala in a lot nicer and shorter!